# Transaction stuck in pool

Tags: go-ethereum, pending-transactions

All of my transactions was stuck in pool as pending around 2days and not getting broadcast to mainnet.

```
> txpool.status
{
  pending: 4096,
  queued: 1024
}
```

So I have 2 questions here:

1. Will those transactions broadcast if I keep waiting? If the answer is NO then how do I solve this issue?
2. I have 300+ transaction stuck in pending, is it possible to remove those transactions not belong to my node?

Note: This issue happened suddenly and I really don't know why, because my node is working fine and done a lot of transactions in the past 5months. My account is enough eth to pay the fee and don't have any lower nonce stuck before.

Comment: You can send the transactions (same nonce and data and order) again with more gas

Comment: Are those transactions from the same account? Do you have enough ether to pay for them? Is the miner enabled? The geth client may drop transactions if they were not mined, that will cause following transactions with larger nonce to get stuck.

Comment: Those transaction was stuck in geth client didn't even broadcast to mainnet, means my transaction still can't find in etherscan.io or others explorer. I'm sure that my account is enough eth to pay those transaction fee and don't have any lower nonce stuck before.

Comment: @superrman777 If those transactions were broadcasted the first time then they will not re-broadcast again. If your node were disconnected then the first time it connect it will broadcast pending transactions. Inside geth's datadir there is a `transactions.rlp` file, if you remove or rename and restart your queue should be empty.